# How to calculate integral of $f(x)=\sqrt{x^3+2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods, area, simpsons-rule

I just had a math test where I had to use trapezoid rule to estimate the area from $a$ to $b$  under the curve:

$$ f(x) = \sqrt{x^3+2} $$

Is there a way to find the exact area under the curve with an integral or can you only estimate it with Simpson's or trapezoid rule?

I did try putting it through Wolfram Alpha and it told me it was unsolvable.

Comment: [You won't](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+sqrt%28x%5E3%2B2%29&dataset=) [like it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Comment: @J.G. if I didn't have several exams to study for rn I would :P

Comment: The hypergeometric function can be simplified into an [elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral)